# How to use Rails2 when Rails3 is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Hello I have both Rails2 and Rails3(beta 3) installed by Ruby Gems. Everything right now defaults to using Rails3.  For instance `rails myproject` will create a new Rails3 template. How do I override this so everything goes to Rails2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) which allows you to run multiple of Ruby with isolation for sets of gems and other configuration. Really useful for testing and managing multiple versions of Rails.

Comment: Even though I would consider my own answer more "correct" I actually began using RVM instead because I needed to be able to use Ruby 1.9.2-head, hence the reason I accepted this answer

Answer (score 3):

Ok, after some googling, stumbled upon this article: http://www.nomachetejuggling.com/2008/03/12/using-multiple-versions-of-rails/

Just tested it and it works. I just get my exact version of Ruby on Rails, which is 2.3.5 and run rails like so:

```
rails _2.3.5_ myproject
```