# Rails 3.03 and Rails 2.38 -- can they work together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to install a Rails 2.3.10 app if I have Rails 3.0.3 installed on my machine?

for example i'd like to start my server with ruby script/server instead of rails server.

thx

Comment: Is there a particular reason you'd want to use ruby script/server rather than rails server? From the way you've phrased this, it sounds like you want to use both together? Is this correct?

Comment: It is 3.0.3, 2.3.8, 2.3.10 etc..

Comment: i want to use them together as I transition from one to the other

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Rails2 when Rails3 is installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796286/how-to-use-rails2-when-rails3-is-installed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two main ways:

- **Bundler**: you can create a Gemfile and use bundler to silo the gems for each of your installations.  The drawback to this one is that you'll probably have to use "bundle exec *command*" whenever you want to run a command for the version of rails you're using, such as spec or cucumber
- **RVM**: using RVM you can use not only different versions of Ruby, but also separate gemsets within a version of Ruby.  I personally use this method most of the time, creating a gemset called "rails3" and "rails2" (or sometimes I use a gemset for the application) with the relevant gem versions in it.  You can have as many gemsets as you want and switch between them.  Stick a .rvmrc file in the root of your application, and rvm will switch the version of ruby and your gemset for you automatically.